# Problem returning json when using fetch in React app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

Guys I am developing a simple weather application using openweatherapp API and React. I am trying to fetch the data in componentDidMount and parse it as JSON. However instead of receiving the JSON, I am receiving the HTML page. When I am trying to hit the API from the browser though, the correct JSON is returned.

I would really appreciate some help, I will post my code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CurrentWeatherForecast } from "./components/CurrentWeatherForecast";
import { NextDaysWeatherForecast } from "./components/NextDaysWeatherForecast";

export class App extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("it mounted");
    fetch(
        "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=1fc71092a81b329e8ce0e1ae88ef0fb7"
    )
        .then((res) => res.text())// this returns the page, if I change to res.json() I receive an error
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CurrentWeatherForecast />
            <NextDaysWeatherForecast />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this returns the page, if I change to res.json() I receive an error` - because the result is NOT json? oh, wait ... it is JSON ... what text **exactly** does it return

Comment: did you set the header?

Comment: @jaromandaX the result is json because I can see it returned in the browser if I am using that link.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 @Phobos

Comment: @RobertoChirila - external (to your site) links need to start with `http://` or `https://` or at least `//`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add 'https://' to your query URL. Server is returning a 404 page.

Comment: i.e. it's trying to fetch `http://your server/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=1fc71092a81b329e8ce0e1ae88ef0fb7`

Comment: @RobertoChirila - thing is, you should check in the browser dev console the response - then you wouldn't have said that it DOES return JSON - when clearly the response was YOUR SERVERS 404 page :p